# IOS: Press and drag in button on custom keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard

I'm building custom keyboard and i want to make response like stock keyboard.
- I can press and hold on one key and drag to other key and so release, the letter will be enter is the one at current finger position
- Can press and hold one key and use other finger to press on the other key and so 2 letters will be entered at the same time.

I've tried many methods in UIButton ( `TouchUpInside, TouchDown, TouchUpOutside ...` but didn't successed.

Answer (score 2):

You are going beyond the abilities of `UIButton`. You need to look at creating a custom view which handles [*Multitouch Events*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH5-SW9).

It's not easy, but it's not impossible either.

Comment: do you have any sample code or clue how to do it ? (logic code) because i really don't know how to do it. I see swiftkey can do it.